# a faster way to download multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, browser

i need to download about 2 million files from the SEC website. each file has a unique url and is on average 10kB. this is my current implementation:

```
    List<string> urls = new List<string>();
    // ... initialize urls ...
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        browser.Navigate(url);
        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(browser.DocumentStream);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(), url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/')));
        sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();
    }
```

the projected time is about 12 days... is there a faster way?

**Edit:** btw, the local file handling takes only 7% of the time

**Edit:** this is my final implementation:

```
    void Main(void)
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;
        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        // ... initialize urls ...
        int retries = urls.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).Sum(arg => downloadFile(arg));
    }

    public int downloadFile(string url)
    {
        int retries = 0;

        retry:
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webrequest.Timeout = 10000;
            webrequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
            webrequest.Proxy = null;
            webrequest.KeepAlive = false;
            webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

            using (Stream sr = webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (FileStream sw = File.Create(url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'))))
            {
                sr.CopyTo(sw);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            if (ee.Message != "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." && ee.Message != "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.")
            {
                if (ee.Message.StartsWith("The operation has timed out") || ee.Message == "Unable to connect to the remote server" || ee.Message.StartsWith("The request was aborted: ") || ee.Message.StartsWith("Unable to read data from the trans­port con­nec­tion: ") || ee.Message == "The remote server returned an error: (408) Request Timeout.") retries++;
                else MessageBox.Show(ee.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                goto retry;
            }
        }

        return retries;
    }
```

Comment: Can't these files be combined into an archive and downloaded in a unit?

Comment: Any reason you're using a browser control instead of a `WebRequest`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos the reason is that i am clueless about the differences...

Comment: @CodeInChaos I tested with a sequential WebRequest, it is actually 30% slower

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Execute the downloads concurrently instead of sequentially, and set a sensible MaxDegreeOfParallelism otherwise you will try to make too many simultaneous request which will look like a DOS attack:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var urls = new List<string>();
        Parallel.ForEach(
            urls, 
            new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10},
            DownloadFile);
    }

    public static void DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create(url)                                               
           .GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        using(var sw = new StreamWriter(url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'))))
        {
            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
```

Comment: looks very dubious to me. You're using a shared instance of browser from multiple threads. And calling `Application.DoEvents` from another thread is probably wrong too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, agreed,  I focussed on the parallelism without considering the download implementation. will fix..

Comment: ..now fixed, replaced browser control with HttpWebRequest

Comment: thanks, i could get a factor of 4 speedup with this method (also using ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;) i guess this is due to server restrictions. any further suggestions?

Comment: The bottleneck is I suspect is the number of concurrent connections per client (IP address) at the server.  If you know what that is set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to match, this won;t increase through but will prevent requests waiting for a connection.  To get more throughput if you have the resources you could scale out, i.e. split the URLs between n-clients each with a distinct IP address to run concurrently.

Answer (score 8):

Download files in several threads. Number of threads depends on your throughput. Also, look at  [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) classes. Simple sample:

```
var list = new[] 
{ 
    "http://google.com", 
    "http://yahoo.com", 
    "http://stackoverflow.com" 
}; 

var tasks = Parallel.ForEach(list,
        s =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"starting to download {s}");
                string result = client.DownloadString((string)s);
                Console.WriteLine($"finished downloading {s}");
            }
        });
```

Comment: The only thing missing here is to set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism.  The OP states 2 million files so without it the above will queue 2 million work items and make way more concurrent requests to the server that it will allow and/or handle.  It's best to throttle it to the max connections per client of the target server.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use several threads in parallel, with a `WebClient`. I recommend setting the max degree of parallelism to the number of threads you want, since unspecified degree of parallelism doesn't work well for long running tasks. I've used 50 parallel downloads in one of my projects without a problem, but depending on the speed of an individual download a much lower might be sufficient.

If you download multiple files in parallel from the same server, you're by default limited to a small number (2 or 4) of parallel downloads. While the http standard specifies such a low limit, many servers don't enforce it. Use `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;` to increase the limit.

Comment: indeed ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000; turned out to be critical in order to get speedups higher than 2

Answer (score 1):

I think the code from o17t H1H' S'k seems right and all but to perform I/O bound tasks an async method should be used.
Like this:

```
public static async Task DownloadFileAsync(HttpClient httpClient, string url, string fileToWriteTo)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    using Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create);
    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
}
```

`Parallel.Foreach` is also available with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. `Parallel.Foreach` has a lot of features that the async does't has, but most of them are also depracticed. You can implement an Producer Consumer system with `Channel` or `BlockingCollection` to handle the amount of 2 million files. But only if you don't know all URLs at the start.

```
private static async void StartDownload()
{
    (string, string)[] urls = new ValueTuple<string, string>[]{
        new ("https://dotnet.microsoft.com", "C:/YoureFile.html"),
        new ( "https://www.microsoft.com", "C:/YoureFile1.html"),
        new ( "https://stackoverflow.com", "C:/YoureFile2.html")};
    var client = new HttpClient();
    ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls, options, async (url, token) =>
        {
            await DownloadFileAsync(httpClient, url.Item1, url.Item2);
        });
}
```

Also look into this [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Shard.DonwloadLibrary). The [Github Wiki](https://github.com/Meyn1/DownloadLibrary/wiki) gives examples how to use it. To download 2 million files this is a good library and has also a retry function. To download a file you only have to create an instance of `LoadRequest` and it downloads it with the name of the file into the Downloads directory.

```
private static void StartDownload()
{
    string[] urls = new string[]{
        "https://dotnet.microsoft.com",
        "https://www.microsoft.com",
      " https://stackoverflow.com"};
    foreach (string url in urls)
        new LoadRequest(url).Start();
}
```

I hope this helps to improve the code.