# Download multiple files at once, no explicit controls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I wish to download around 100,000 files from a web site. The answers from [this qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869812/a-faster-way-to-download-multiple-files) have the same issues as what I tried.

I have tried two approaches, both of which use highly erratic amounts of bandwidth:

The first attempts to synchronously download the files:

```
        ParallelOptions a = new ParallelOptions();
        a.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10000;

        Parallel.For(start, end, a, i =>
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

This works, but my throughput looks like this:
[image]

The second way involves using semaphore and async to do the parallelism more manually (without the semaphores it will obviously spawn too many work items):

```
Parallel.For(start, end, a, i =>
        {
            list.Add(getAndPreprocess(/*get URL from somewhere*/);
        });
```

...

```
static async Task getAndPreprocess(string url)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        sem.WaitOne();
        string content = "";
        try
        {
            var data = client.GetStringAsync(url);
            content = await data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message); sem.Release(); return; }
        sem.Release();
        try
        {
            //try to use results from content
        }
        catch { return; }
    }
```

My throughput now looks like this:
[image]

Is there a nice way to do this, such that it starts downloading anouther file when the speed falls, and stops adding when the aggregate speed is constant (like what you would expect a download manager to do)?

Additionally, even though the second form gives better results, I dislike that I have to use semaphores, as it is error prone.

What the standard way to do this?

**Note:** these are all small files (<50KB)