# How to download correctly files simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am trying to download mltiple files simultaneosly. But all files are downloading one by one, sequantilly. So, at first this file downloaded `@"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf"`, and then this file is started to dowload `@"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland-latest.osm.pbf",`, and the next file to be downloaded is `@"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf"` and so on.

But I would like to download **simultaneously**.

So I've the following code based on [the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747645/download-multiple-files-in-parallel-using-c-sharp):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await DownloadFiles();
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public static async Task DownloadFiles()
{
    IList<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf"
    };

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        string fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'));
        await DownloadFile(url, fileName);
    }            
}

public static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string fileName)
{
    string address = @"D:\Downloads";
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, $"{address}{fileName}");
    }
}
```

However, when I see in my file system, then I see that files are downloading **one by one, sequantially,** not simultaneosuly:

[image]

In addition, I've tried to use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869812/a-faster-way-to-download-multiple-files), however there are no simultaneous downloads:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf"
    };

    Parallel.ForEach(urls,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
        DownloadFile);
}

public static void DownloadFile(string url)
{
    string address = @"D:\Downloads";
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url)
           .GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(address + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'))))
    {
        sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how it is possible to download simultaneosly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By calling `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` you are running you code synchronously. Which .NET version are you using? What about `HttpClient` and `async Main()`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I am using .NET 4.6. Could you show how it is possible to do? Is there better ways?

Comment: try to define `Main` as `static async Task Main(string[] args) ` and just call ` await DownloadFiles();` inside

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        string fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'));
        await DownloadFile(url, fileName); // you wait to download the item and then move the next
    }
```

Instead you should create tasks and wait all of them to complete.

```
public static Task DownloadFiles()
{
    IList<string> urls = new List<string>
    {
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf",
        @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf"
    };

       var tasks = urls.Select(url=> {
           var fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'));
             return DownloadFile(url, fileName);    
         }).ToArray();   
         return Task.WhenAll(tasks);       
}
```

Rest of your code can remain same.

Comment: thanks for your response! Could you write the whole code? I cannot understand where should I put these code.

Comment: @Learner See my more complete answer. Eldar's code as it is does not work correctly.

Comment: @user2966445 the code uses the `DownloadFiles` function awaits the function already.

Comment: @user2966445 *You can't return Task.WhenAll(tasks)* -> sure you can. It returns a `Task` that can be awaited further up in the call stack. Whether you really want that is a different thing.

Comment: @Eldar I've tried to put your code, however, I see many errors.

Comment: @PeterBons I see what Eldar did. Async was removed from the signature, that makes the difference. I think both of our versions net the same result then.

Comment: @Learner There was an  extra `}` i removed it. It should work. I'm not used to write code without and IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Eldar's solution works with some minor edits. This is the full working `DownloadFiles` method that was edited:

```
public static async Task DownloadFiles()
{
    IList<string> urls = new List<string>
{
    @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf",
    @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/finland-latest.osm.pbf",
    @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain-latest.osm.pbf",
    @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf",
    @"http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/belgium-latest.osm.pbf"
};

    var tasks = urls.Select(t => {
        var fileName = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf('/'));
        return DownloadFile(t, fileName);
    }).ToArray();   

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works! Now I do not know what answer should be accepted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

this will download them asynchronously one after each other.

```
await DownloadFile(url, fileName);
await DownloadFile(url2, fileName2);
```

this will do what you actually want to achieve:

```
var task1 = DownloadFile(url, fileName);
var task2 = DownloadFile(url2, fileName2);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: You should remove awaits in the second sample.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, If I have 100 files, then should I write 100 times these lines `var task1 = DownloadFile(url, fileName);`?

Comment: @Learner no, you shouldnt. That was just to describe how it is done "in parallel". you can use a for loop like shown in the other answers.